# Node.js + OracleDB : ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

Hello you beautiful people you.

I'm trying to create REST APIs using node.js connected to an OracleDB, but i'm pulling my hair out trying to get these stupid bind variables working.

Here's my code:

```
app.get('/mailsummary/:SCHEMA', function (req, res) {
    "use strict";

    oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            // Error connecting to DB
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                status: 500,
                message: "Error connecting to DB",
                detailed_message: err.message
            }));
            return;
        }

        connection.execute("select * from :SCHEMA.event@db3", [req.params.SCHEMA], {
            outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT // Return the result as Object
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err || result.rows.length < 1) {
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                var status = err ? 500 : 404;
                res.status(status).send(JSON.stringify({
                    status: status,
                    message: err ? "Error getting vendor mailing summary." : "Vendor or DB does nto exist.",
                    detailed_message: err ? err.message : ""
                }));
            } else {
                res.contentType('application/json').status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
            }
            // Release the connection
            connection.release(
                function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log("GET /mailsummary/" + req.params.SCHEMA + " : Connection released");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
});
```

For some reason i'm getting the error

```
OracleDB : ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

If I remove the bind variable, assign a static value and remove "req.params.SCHEMA" after the sql statement and leave the brackets blank, it works.

```
connection.execute("select * from peeps.event@db3", [], {
            outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT // Return the result as Object
```

I know it's got to be something simple with the way i'm pulling in the bind variable, but i'm pulling my hair out.

Please help me Obi-Wan Kenobi... you're my only hope.

Thanks!

Comment: I also managed to somehow get "ORA-00903: invalid table name\n" on occasion through all this testing.  Though i'm positive the table name is correct... but perhaps the bind variable is adding something wonky in?

Answer (score 0):

Bind variables are placeholders used to transfer data between database and client program.  You are trying to transfer the text of the SQL statement - your usage won't work.

This bind behavior is not specific to node-oracledb; it's the way Oracle works.  It helps keep data and statement text separate.

There is some general bind info at: http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNOCI/binding-and-defining-in-oci.htm#GUID-77A26CEA-1C41-46A2-866C-622F9FEB5482

Comment: Thank you Christopher!  Is there a better way for me to transpose a variable from a page into the SQL statement?

Comment: Have a whitelist of valid variables and reject anything else.